# Subsurface overhang causing black shading

Tags: mirror, subdivision-surface, shadows, bevel

I've got a model with mirror, bevel, and subsurf modifiers on it and subsurface is causing some shading issues. I don't know how to fix them other than to just disable it. I've seen another two posts like this but one of them was due to some tris in the corners of the mesh, which I don't think I have.

How do I fix this?
[image]
[Here's a download for the .blend file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01532684199910961530)

edit: By request, a screenshot of it without subsurf in edit mode. There are no ngons, it's all quads.[image]

Comment: It looks like you have ngons in the mesh. Can you post a photo of your mesh in edit mode with subsurf disabled?

Comment: Ashtutosh Budheo, I've added a screenshot in edit mode without the subsurf. I think I've done a fairly good job with the topology, as it's all quads.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the topology automatically generated by the *Bevel* modifier creates these artifacts, maybe someone will explain. To correct it, you can add some edge loops not too far. Or you can create bevels manually, first horizontally then vertically, it creates a different topology that works better.

[image]